# What are the session limits in Voximplant?

Tags: voximplant

I received the "JS error: Exceeded the total HTTP connection count limit!", error in Voximplant Platform today, but I can't find the limits. Where do I find this information?

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions in Voximplant Javascript engine. One of them limits number of concurrent HTTP requests being made from the call scenario - only 3 requests can be processed simultaneously.
You should consider adjusting scenario flow to reduce number of simultaenous requests. For example, you can use [httpRequestAsync](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/net/httprequestasync) and chain requests using `await`.
Full list of sandbox restrictions can be found [here](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/voxengine/limits).